# how to add screen share function using PeerJS?

Tags: webrtc, peerjs

Currently, i am working on a webRTC project where you can give call and receive call.i also want to add screen share functionality to it.

can anyone provide me a good documentation link?
i am currently following the official  [documentation](https://peerjs.com/) of peerJS.
i was able to do audio-video calling but stuck on the screen sharing part.
Help Me!

Answer (score 2):

You need to get stream just like you do with getUserMedia and then you give that stream to PeerJS.

It should be something like this:

```
var displayMediaOptions = {
    video: {
        cursor: "always"
    },
    audio: false
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displayMediaOptions)
.then(function (stream) {
    // add this stream to your peer 
});
```

Comment: how can i pass the stream and show it to the other user??

Comment: you can check this out https://github.com/mluketin/peerjs-helloworld-conference/blob/master/index.js

instead of getUserMedia, you would use getDisplayMedia in my answer above

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with and learning about WebRTC. From what I've read, I think the solution here probably hinges on [`getDisplayMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia). That's also what [this React, Node and peerJS tutorial suggests](https://dev.to/arjhun777/video-chatting-and-screen-sharing-with-react-node-webrtc-peerjs-18fg) (though I haven't tried it myself yet).

Comment: getDisplayMedia is for getting the video; but how can I pass it to other users??

Answer (score 0):

```
let screenShare = document.getElementById('shareScreen');
    screenShare.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: { mediaSource: "screen" }
        });
        //Instead of adminId, pass peerId who will taking captureStream in call
        myPeer.call(adminId, captureStream);
    })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).